# Failed to fetch device token without exposure notification

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I am searching for the token as soon as I enter the application

When I generate the APK file and install it on my cell phone, the token comes empty, undefined or even gives an error

[image]

`"react": "18.2.0", "expo": "~49.0.15", "react-native": "0.72.6"`

```
  async function onSubmit() {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true)

      const pushToken = await registerForPushNotificationsAsync()

      const newData = {
        email: userEmail,
        password: userPassword,
        token: pushToken?.data
      }

      Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(newData.token, null, 2))
```

```
export async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
  let token: Notifications.ExpoPushToken

  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
      name: 'default',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
    })
  }

  if (Device.isDevice) {

    const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync()
    let finalStatus = existingStatus

    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync()

      finalStatus = status
    }

    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!')
      return
    }

    token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
      projectId: Constants.expoConfig.extra.eas.projectId,
    })

    //registerDevicePushTokenAsync(token)
    console.log('')
    return token

  } else {
    alert('Must use physical device for Push Notifications')
  }
}
```

I tried to lower the versions to SDK 48, expo-notifications 0.18

but they all keep giving the same error

I need to redeem this token to make notifications